# Center views using *only* visual format?

Tags: ios, visual-format-language

I'm trying to center 2 views with different height vertically.

```
UILabel *view1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view1.text = @"view1\nline2";
view1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
view1.numberOfLines = 0;
UILabel *view2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
view2.text = @"view2\nline2";
view2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
view2.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.view addSubview:view1];
[self.view addSubview:view2];

NSDictionary *views = @{@"view1": view1, @"view2" : view2};

[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

for (UIView *view in views.allValues) {
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view1]-[view2(==view1)]-|"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=20)-[view1(200)]-(>=20)-|"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=20)-[view2(100)]-(>=20)-|"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:nil views:views]];
```

This manages to make the centers of both aligned vertically, but they are at the bottom of the superview! 
[image]

I want to center vertically not only relative to each other, also in the superview.

I added a constraint like this and it works:

```
[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

[image]

But I want to know, is this possible to achieve using only with visual format?

Comment: I use PureLayout for this kind of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only by adding spacer views. So if you create a couple of views, lets call them spacer1 and spacer2, you can center view1 with this string,

```
@"V:|[spacer1][view1][spacer2(==spacer1)]|"
```

This assumes that view1 has a fixed height. I wouldn't recommend doing it this way though, I would just use the code you show at the bottom of your post.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems visual format is quite limited. So it's supposed to be combined with "traditional" constraints.

Answer (score 0):

What about calculating the Y in "metrics" ?

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-centerY-[view1(200)]-(>=20)-|"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:@{@"centerY": @(CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)/2.0 - 100)}
                                                                    views:views]];
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't work when you rotate the view, unless you put it somewhere where it will be updated (and then you have to remove the old one first).

Comment: maybe mixing it with Size classes ?